# Is there a name for the category of games where you use programming code to fight each other?

Tags: terminology

I don't know if I dreamt about this or if it exists, here is the setup:

- One textfield for code-input (probably javascript)
- A playground with two or more robots/tanks.

By writing instructions you can decide how the robots should behave and have them battle each other out. The robots are autonomous once the game starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia calls this a [programming game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_game).